# TclError: bad geometry specifier

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I tried to define geometry for Tkinter GUI using following script using python Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk() 
w=300
h=200
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)    
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.mainloop()`
```

I'm getting following error:

```
 TclError: bad geometry specifier "1920*1200+150+100".
```

Comment: The error looks like you're using `'%d*%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y)` instead of `'%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y)`. Are you sure you use the x and not the *?

Comment: ya You are correct i used * instead of x...  Now It is working

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so everyone can see that the question has been answered.

Comment: Also `rot.geometry(...` should be `root.geometry(...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error looks like you're using `'%d*%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y)` instead of `'%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y)`.
Are you sure you use the `x` and not the `*`?

Answer (score 1):

Use x(character) instead of *

```
root.geometry("100x100")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`main_application.geometry('1200x800')`

not

`main_application.geometry('1200*800')`

The difference is between `x` and `*`

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you use "x" this not "*" this.

Answer (score 0):

Even this does not works because there are blankspaces:

```
root.geometry('200x100 + 300 + 250')
```

So you should also be careful to not include any space between the numbers and the + symbols. This works:

```
root.geometry('200x100+300+250')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is also to check the type of the parameters.
It should be int.

```
return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
```

_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "800x600+368.0+132.0"

Correct it by:
self.root.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (self.FrameSizeX,self.FrameSizeY,int(FramePosX),int(FramePosY)))